# Is it possible to create a directory within a zipfile object in Go?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, concurrency, zip

I am using goroutines to concurrently download data from S3. For context, I currently have a group of samples. Each sample contains data in the form of a map, with a key representing the name of a file and the value pointing to the path in S3. Each sample has about 10 files that need to be downloaded from S3. I download all of these files in parallel and write to a shared zipfile object (got the mutexes and stuff figured out). I've figured out the concurrency aspect of this problem but the issue I face is organizing the zipfile object. I was wondering if it was possible to create a subdirectory within a zipfile object. otherwise i'm left with a massive zip object of all the data I need, but it is not really organized in any tangible way. Ideally, I'd be able to create a folder in the zipfile object for each sample and save all the file data to that but i don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [zip format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) has no notion of folder / directory, it just contains a list of files.

The file names may be composed to have folders in them, so the folders are just "virtual" but are not recorded as they are in "real" file systems.

So no, you can't create a directory in a zip file.